# How to use different fill color for certain points (e.g outliers) in geom_violin plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, outliers, violin-plot

I would like to highlight outliers using a different color in the same violin plot, looks like this:
[image]
Here is an example data with outliers and my code trying to produce the results:

```
dat <- cars[1:30, "dist"]  # original data
dat <- c(dat, c(190, 186, 210, 220, 218)) # add outliers
df <- data.frame(x= "", y = dat)
df$outlier <- ifelse(df$y %in% boxplot.stats(df$y)$out, "yes", "no")
# plotting
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_violin(data = df[df$outlier == "yes",], aes(fill = "outiler")) +
  geom_violin(data = df[df$outlier == "no",], aes(fill = "non-outlier")) +
  scale_fill_manual(name=NULL, values=c(outiler="red", `non-outlier`="black"))
```

[image]

However, as you can see, I do not know how to make the width of two violin plots in the same scale.

Is there any way to achieve using different fill color to label outliers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
dat <- cars[1:30, "dist"]  # original data
dat <- c(dat, c(190, 186, 210, 220, 218)) # add outliers
df <- data.frame(x= "", y = dat)
df$outlier <- ifelse(df$y %in% boxplot.stats(df$y)$out, "red", "black")
# plotting
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
geom_violin(data = df, aes(fill = outlier))
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I would like to have outliers and non-outlier in the same violin, not separated.